# Atom shows only grey files, even when they are changed

Tags: git, file, atom-editor, color-scheme

I've just set up a new laptop. On my old laptop, every time I changed a file, it changed colours (e.g. green, when it has been created, yellow if it has been changed).

Now on my new laptop all files are always displayed as grey.

I've googled this and it seems to have something to do with Git, but as far as I know I have never used Git. I'm open for using it though :)

How can I get the colour scheme back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing files in a git repository, Atom can use a plugin such as `git-plus` to perform git operations from within the UI.
The plugin also provides the colors for the file names, as you mentioned: grey for files that haven't changed, green for new files, etc.

You can install the plugin from the **Install Packages** menu under settings.

To have your files in a git repository, you'll need git installed, and then run `git init` inside the project root directory.

A nice git tutorial can be found [here](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what NimrodArgov had said, I would like to add the following:

If you are going to be using git, you can have a colored console output to view additions/deletions in files and staged/committed files by setting `git config --global color.ui auto` in your terminal after installing git.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)